# Correlated Subquery with All operator

Tags: sql

I am having trouble running this query:

```
select empname,empnum 
from emp a
where a.sal> All (select sal from emp b where b.hiredate<a.hiredate)
```

Error message:

> all subquery with Correlated experssion is not supported

the query should make sure to present all employees which their salary is higher than anyone hired after them

while this query works:

```
select ename,empnum 
from emp a
where not exists (select sal from emp b where b.hiredate<a.hiredate and b.sal>a.sal)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you areusing.

Comment: So to clarify, what exactly are you hoping to learn from the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this with aggregation for a query that is almost equivalent:

```
select empname, empnum
from emp e
where e.sal > (select max(e2.sal)
               from emp e2
               where e2.hiredate < e.hiredate
              );
```

The only difference is that your query will return the employee with the oldest hired date, whereas this does not.  You can tweak it as:

```
select empname, empnum
from emp e
where e.sal > (select coalesce(max(e2.sal), e.sal - 1)
               from emp e2
               where e2.hiredate < e.hiredate
              );
```

Note that the use of *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: thank you for the help appreciated! But still I wanted to understand why the 'ALL ' operator not working in my presented solution ..I searched online and didn't  encounter any claim about adding '>ALL' to a correlated subquery as problematic . what is this Error message ?

Comment: @ShadyAbs . . . The error message is quite clear:  The database you are using doesn't support what you are trying to do.